# React state really slow on a text input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a text input which looks like this:

```
<input
    placeholder="Search by City, Zip Code, or Name"
    type="text"
    className="searchBar"
    value={this.state.search}
    onChange={(e) => this.setState({ search: e.target.value })}
    onKeyDown={this.keySearch}
></input>
```

My problem here is let's say I type the word hello. Only after 5 seconds does it show up, and each type I type a letter it takes 5 seconds to show up in the text input. It should be instantaneous.

This is not a browser or computer problem.

On another page on my website a have a text input written similarly to the one above, and it is perfectly fine.

Is this because I have so much state in my constructor?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      shops: [],
      burger: "0",
      pointerEvents: "none",
      width: "30px",
      logout: "none",
      login: "flex",
      loadingMAP: true,
      search: "",
      modal: true,
      addresses: [],
      currentPosition: {},
      userLocation: { lat: 39.0119, lng: -98.4842 },
      zoom: 4,
      loadingMAP2: "block",
      dashboard: "none",
      FetchingData: "block",
      showMap: "flex",
      gridlistDisplay: "flex",
      showmaptext: "Show map",
      MapBoxDisplay: "block",
      loadingShopBusinesses: "none",
      shopbusinessesmapbox: [],
      count: 0,
    };
  }
```

Or is this another problem?

Please help and thanks.

My full code:

https://gist.github.com/rherugu/510fabd4dd89da080a843f61ec1881e0

Comment: Could you please share the whole component? You also have the keySearch function that may have an affect.

Comment: No, state isn't the problem. This looks OK--please show a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: The most likely cause of your problem is that your render method calls too many expensive function. You should look into memoizing some of the values your render function needs

Comment: It is probably something else in that component that takes some time to render. Please share the rest of the component and we might figure it out :)

Comment: Ok, I added my code in a gist. its quite long :)

Comment: Do you realize that every single time your user types a letter, your entire render method gets re-executed, and the entire UI has to be re-rendered? You should probably break things up more into separate components, so that changing the search text doesn't inherently force everything to re-render.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. How would I do this? Also, why does the entire UI re-render? Also, I tried returning false from a shoudComponentUpdate but then my whole page doesn't work.